# Does the null object pattern make sense without checks only?

Tags: java, design-patterns, null

If one still uses checks for a null object according to the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), is this still *legal* use of the null object pattern or is one violating it already?

```
public class Example {

   private static final Example NULL = new Example(new Object());

   public static Example getNull() {
       return NULL;
   }

   private Object member;

   public Example(Object member) {
       this.member = member;
   }
}

public class Manager {
   public operation(Example example) {
      if(Example.getNull().equals(example) == false) {
          doSomething(example);
      }
   }
}
```

Ideally one would have a null object that could be called directly with `doSomething(example)` without checks. But if one needs such a check, does it still make sense to avoid `null` at all?

Comment: Post this question also on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the idea of this design pattern is exactly for NOT having to check if an object is null

Comment: It's more like a "NO-OP" than properly a "null" IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the `Null Object Pattern` should be used to avoid checking if a value is absent or not. The responsibility of the `Null Object` is to behave correctly in case no value is available. For example, if a method processes each item of a collection, instead of using `null` if no items are available and checking for `null` to avoid iteration over each element, use an empty collection as `Null Object`. This way no special case has to be implemented.

If your code checks for `null` or if the reference is the `Null Object`, you do not get any benefit from the `Null Object Pattern`.

Comment: I feared the great impact of that answer, but I begin to think that otherwise Guava Optional is the better choice.

Comment: Using `Guavas Optional` can achieve the same effect as the `Null Object`. If you fetch the value of an `Optional` by using the `or()` method, providing a value as default which eliminates the special case handling in your code, you get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The `public` façade's methods, published as the API, should check for not-null params; if one of them is null and you envisioned for it the *null object pattern*, those methods should replace it with a NULL object instance (which would work as a 'default case') and forward it to the back-end methods, which therefore should have no need to do that check.

Comment: Don't really get the message of that answer, sorry.

Comment: I meant: if you are getting the Example instance from a parameter of a public method, you still have to check for it being not-null, and if so you must replace it with your NULL object. All the following calls to package/private methods do not have to check it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's valid to check for Null as long as it only happens very rarely. If the check is systematic, then you obviously do not get any benefit, but  it can be necessary to perform the check on some specific corner case.

On your example, using the pattern would result on the following code :

```
public class Manager {
   public operation(Example example) {
           example.doSomething(example); // does nothing when example is the Null Object
   }
}
```

But as `doSomething` is not a method of your object, it might be necessary to do the check (depending of what this method does, of course).

Comment: In the beginning I really liked this answer, but after some more coding it really feels like Guava Optional is the better choice for me.